# Fail to train custom model of Tensorflow from tf2 model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I want to train my custom model using Faster RCNN ResNet50 V1 and I have run the following command:

```
Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
   --model_dir=Tensorflow/workspace/models/faster_rcnn_resnet50_v1 \
   --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow/workspace/models/faster_rcnn_resnet50_v1/pipeline.config \
   --num_train_steps=2000
```

Then I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 265, in _check_feature_extractor_exists
    'Tensorflow'.format(feature_extractor_type))
ValueError:  is not supported. See `model_builder.py` 
         for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow.
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

The information from you suggests to me that the name of the feature extractor is wrong in your config file. The correct way would be to specify the feature extractor in your config file as follows :

```
feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_resnet50_keras'
      batch_norm_trainable: true
    }
```

Set the `batch_norm_trainable` to `false` if you are fine-tuning on a smaller dataset.

An example of a right config file for `resnet50_V1` is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/configs/tf2/faster_rcnn_resnet50_v1_1024x1024_coco17_tpu-8.config).